# How to upload multiple files at same time in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a function to upload images in CakePHP 2. It works fine, but only upload 1 file at same time. How to upload multiple images at same time. Sorry about my English!

Controller

```
  public function add() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'File');
        $this->loadModel('File');

        if(!empty($this->data)){
        $data = $this->data;

        $file = $data['File']['filename'];


        if($file['name'] != null){
            $data = $this->data;   
            $file =  $data['File']['filename'];
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'uploads/' . $file['name']);
            $data['File']['title'] = $this->data['File']['title'];
            $data['File']['description'] = $this->data['File']['description'];
            $data['File']['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $this->File->save($data,false);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Added.', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'file'));
        }else{

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wrong', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'file'));
        }
        }
}
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('filename', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$this->loadModel('File');` <- very dangerous. Your model file name conflicts with [the core File class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/File.php#L26).

Comment: Hi there's a great tutorial on how to upload multiple files in this blog http://unselfishideas.blogspot.com/2014/08/attaching-multiple-files-in-cakephp.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed answer.

The basic structure is the following:

**View:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Model',  array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('image.0', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('image.1', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('image.2', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('image.3', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save All');
```

**Controller:**

```
function index()
{    
   if($this->request->is('post', 'put'))
   {
       $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data['image']);
   }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function beforeSave()
{
    foreach($this->data as $k, $v)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('files.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));
```

You can then loop through the files array and process them as usual inside controller function.
Check [CakeBakery.](http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/01/31/HTML-5-Multiple-File-Upload-With-Cake.html)